# How to filter item based on StartDate and ExpireDate?

Tags: filter

I have an announcement list with StartDate (datetime with time) and EndDate (datetime with time). I am adding 15 future annoucements and i would like to automatically display item or items when start time is equal or greater than today and end time is less than or equal to today. I put in some future announcements which should not show up in the view but they are. What am i doing wrong?

It's like this announcement ([How to Edit or Add Announcements](http://cms.skidmore.edu/help/faq/announcements.cfm)) but in SharePoint 2010.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the filter that you added on your view within Modify View Settings?

Comment: Hi Ransher, Just updated the original post with the print shot. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your filtering is wrong. You need to display items where start date is equal or **less than** today and expire date is **greater than** or equal to today.

Assuming start date is less than expire date, no single item will be displayed based on your current filter.

Comment: Thank you pholpar. it worked like charm. I appreciate it.